# Code Make multilanguage app in windows mobile

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-mobile, multilingual

I'm new in Windows Mobile and I want to create a multilanguage windows mobile app to make the app change its language from English to Arabic and Vice Versa.

How Can I do this in code?

Hope anyone can help me.

Comment: If this device is indeed a Windows Phone 7 device, you should remove the Windows Mobile tag. Windows Mobile was only able to work with about 5 languages.

Comment: Still not clear if this is Windows Phone or Windows Mobile related question! And, BTW; you can encode as much languages as you like inside your application. As long as you provide the fonts....

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by localising your app 
first of all you will have to add a resource file of arabic in ehich there will be a property name and its translation and in the other file there should be same property name and its translation in english and then you will have to bind that property where you want that text to be displayed .

Like this

```
Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Fare,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
```

where fare is the name of the property. so if the app is in english than that property will give value of fare in english else it will give it in arabic